# Add row only on small device - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu in two sections. 3 li elements in the top, and 2 in the bottom, separated with a row.

But when I view it from a small device i would like to align all li element to be in a row so they are separated.

Is there a way to use bootstrap to make a row active only on small devices? I tried using visible-xs but that hides the menu on the big device.

```
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 nav1">

         <nav>
          <ul>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
          <li><a cla target="_blank" href="#"><center><b>Toyota</b></center></a> </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><center><b>Hyndai </b></center></a> </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><center><b>Nissan</b></center></a> </li>
          </div>
         </ul>
         </nav>

      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 nav2">
        <nav>
        <ul>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><center><b>Varebiler</b></center></a> </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><center><b>Brugte biler</b></center></a> </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for all the answers.

I ended up going in the other direction. I didn't want two different navs.
I used some CSS to solve the problem.

```
 @media (max-width: 992px) 
{
    .nav1 ul li
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .last-child
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy to add  a row only in a small device in bootstrap .

```
<div class="row visible-sm">
 ... 
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with `visible-*` class, but you forgot about the opposing `hidden-*` class, where `*` can be `lg, md, sm or xs`. The way you get this layout working is as such:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row visible-lg visible-md hidden-xs hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Toyota</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Hyundai</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Nissan</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row visible-lg visible-md hidden-xs hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Varebiler</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Brugte Biler</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Toyota</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Hyundai</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Nissan</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Varebiler</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Brugte Biler</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that his renders a total of 7 `.row`'s inside your container, 2 of which only show when the screen is `lg` or `md`, and the other 5 only show when the screen is `sm` or `xs`. Check out this Bootply example to see the code in effect:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9AejpzWcHq)

Hope this helps! Also, be cautious using `col-*-*` on non-div elements, they may not render as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I know you tried using only `visible-xs` but try making two menus:

One with `visible-xs`, it will not show on larger devices.

Another with `hidden-xs`, it will not show on extra-small devices.

This combination will achieve the desired result. It is the most effecient way to accomplish this using **only** bootstrap. There are several other methods using Javascript, however.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the margin from your `ul` object.

Adding this css solves the problem:

```
ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

see this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JK3bqP2rup) for an example.